# Highschool (year 12) homework question (statistical analysis)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am getting stuck on part b of the following question

A company manufactures bricks with normally distributed weights. The mean weight is 0.96kg with standard deviation 0.045kg

a) Let Y be the mean of weight of 9 such bricks. Find the distribution of Y
b) What is the probability that a random sample of 9 bricks has mean weight more than 1kg?

So my answer for a is
$Y \sim N(0.96, 0.045^{2})$

However, I don't know where to start for b). Could someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Part a) is wrong. $N(0.96, 0.045^2)$ is the distribution of a single brick's weight, but you are asked to find the distribution of the mean of 9 bricks' weights. For b) you are asked to compute the probability that $Y \ge 1$. If you know the distribution of $Y$, then you can use what you know about normal distributions to compute this probability (possibly with the aid of a normal table or a computer).

Comment: @angryavian Could you please show me how to solve part a?

Comment: Assuming the weights of the $9$ bricks are independent, if $S$ is the sum of the weights, then $S\sim N(9\cdot.96,9\cdot.045^2)$  Since $Var(cX)=c^2Var(X)$, $\frac S9\sim N(.96, \frac{.045^2}9)$  Have I made a mistake?

Comment: @saulspatz how is $Var(cX) = c^2Var(X)$? (or basically what does $c$ mean in this?

Comment: @user71207 $c$ is a constant

Comment: Ok, but how is that related to the final statement $\frac S9\sim N(.96, \frac{.045^2}9)$? Why does $Var(cX) = c^2Var(X)$ allow you to conclude that?

Comment: Should the variance not become $9^2 \times .045^2$ using that definition, after you divide everything by $9$, everything reverts back to normal but funny things happen with variance which I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you the general method for such a problem
and let you plug in the specific numbers for your particular problem.

Suppose bricks have weights distributed as
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$ [Notice that in this notation the second parameter is the standard deviation, not the variance.]

(a) The mean $Y = \bar X$ of $n = 9$ such bricks
is distributed as $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$  [That is, $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.]$

(b) You seek 
$$P(\bar X > a) = 
P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} >
            \frac{a - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)
= P\left(Z > \frac{a - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right),$$
where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution.

In the final expression, let $a = 1, \mu=0.96, \sigma = 0.045, n = 9.$ and use a printed table of the standard
normal cumulative distribution function to get your answer.

Using R, in which $\mathtt{pnorm}$ is a normal CDF with
specified parameters, one can get the numerical answer $P(\bar X > 1) = 0.00383$ as shown below. (Because of rounding, your result using printed normal tables will be
slightly less precise.)

```
n = 9; mu = 0.96; sg = 0.045
1 - pnorm(1, mu, sg/sqrt(n))  # last param is SD
[1] 0.003830381
```

In the following picture, the dotted density curve is for the
population of bricks, the solid curve is for the mean of $n = 1$ bricks, and the (small) area under the solid curve to the right of the vertical line represents the desired probability.

[image]

Notes: (1) Roughly speaking the PDF of the population is three times
as wide as the PDF for the PDF of the mean of nine. Thus
in order to include total probability 1 under the curve,
the PDF of the mean must be three times as tall.

(2) R is excellent statistical software, available free of charge for Windows, Mac and Unix computers from [here](https://www.r-project.org/). It is easy to learn to use--provided you use just what you need at each step.